# Export table to a csv file in DBeaver with command

Tags: psql, dbeaver

I am using the following command to export the data

`\copy (select * From table_name) To 'my_path' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;`
But I get error `syntax error at or near "\"`.
If I use
 `copy (select * From table_name) To 'my_path' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;`
I get the error  `COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`
I really do not know which command I should run. Thanks in advance for your help:))

Comment: `\copy` is not a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html). It's a command implemented by `psql` and can't be used in other SQL clients